# convert a string of numbers to a datetime object

Tags: python, datetime, weekday

I am parsing a .csv file which contains a column of dates in financial datetime format `yyyymmdd`, I need to remove weekends when writing some of the rows out to a different file.

I know to use `datetime.weekdays()` and then:

```
if some_datetime_object.datetime.weekday() != 6 or 1:
    f.write(some_row)
```

however, how would I convert a string parsed in from a csv to a datetime object to allow the `weekday()` function to be used.

Comment: `if some_datetime_object.datetime.weekday() != 6 or 1` does not do what you think it does

Answer (score 1):

You can use `datetime.datetime.strptime`:

```
import datetime
#example date strings
date1 = "20120423"
date2 = "2015-04-23"

datetime_object_1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date1, '%Y%m%d')
datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 23, 0, 0)

datetime_object_2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date1, '%Y-%m-%d')
datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 23, 0, 0)
```

Have a look at the bottom of this [page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) to see all possible directives for the formatter of this function. You can parse almost any string with date/time data using the `strptime` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to a datetime object using [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior). From here, you can use the `weekdays` method.

However, your conditions are inaccurate, if you only want to keep Monday through Friday. Note that [`weekday`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday) returns an integer from 0 to 6 with Monday being 0 and Sunday being 6.

> Return the day of the week as an integer, where Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6.

This means you want to check if the returned value is `5` or `6`.

---

The conditional you have will not work for another reason.

```
if some_datetime_object.datetime.weekday() != 6 or 1:
```

This is saying if the weekday is NOT Sunday OR True. You are short circuiting your conditional and forcing everything to be `True`. You need to make it something like this (with the appropriate values adjusted)

```
if some_datetime_object.datetime.weekday() != 6 and some_datetime_object.datetime.weekday() != 1:
```

I did this differently in the code below by using `not in`

```
if datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y%m%d').weekday() not in (5,6):
```

---

```
import datetime

dates = [
    "20150801",
    "20150802",
    "20150803",
    "20150804",
    "20150805",
    "20150806",
    "20150807",
    "20150808",
    "20150809",
]

for d in dates:
    if datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y%m%d').weekday() not in (5,6):
        print d
```

---

This outputs:

```
20150803
20150804
20150805
20150806
20150807
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from datetime import datetime
date_string = '20150501'
some_datetime_object = datetime(int(date_string[:4]), int(date_string[4:6]), int(date_string[6:]))
```

Your code however won't work, since that if statement is wrongly written. The correct way would be:

```
if some_datetime_object.datetime.weekday() not in (5,6)]:
```